# correct usage with commas in this example

Tags: british-english, commas

While introducing someone, we use commas.

·         This is Jane, my sister.

·         The distinguished scientist, Mr. Stephen, of AKL University, will be addressing the crowd tomorrow.

In the second sentence, the comma before and after the name indicates we are talking about a specific scientist of AKL University. ***The comma after the name also tells us that the information after the name is essential to identify the person.***

https://www.grammar.com/the_correct_way_to_use_commas_with_names_and_titles

Doesn't the comma before the title of the University define it as non-essential not essential to identify the person in this example?

Not least because there would likely be many distinguished scientists within any given University but were talking about a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence could be phrased without a comma as

> This is my sister Jane.

which is now phrased in a way similar to the second sentence. Here, it is the *first* comma which should go.

> The distinguished scientist Mr. Stephen, of AKL University, will be addressing the crowd tomorrow.

It is precisely because Mr Stephen's university is non-essential, that it can be separated by commas (or parentheses).

The important information is that **Mr Stephen** will be speaking, not "the distinguished scientist" – which *describes* Mr Stephen.

Alternatively the sentence could be phrased as

> Mr. Stephen, the distinguished scientist from AKL University, will be addressing the crowd tomorrow.

Here, the part within commas informs who Mr Stephen is and where he is from, for those who might not know of him.